# Should node.js modules export named functions or an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, ecmascript-6

Which is the better pattern to use when creating modules in Node.js that have multiple functions that are called "statically" i.e. not using the `new` keyword. Is there an equivalent in ES6 I am missing?

**Pattern 1.**

```
// math.js
module.exports.add = (x, y) => {
    return x + y;
}

module.exports.multiply = (x, y) => {
    return x * y;
};

// app.js
const math = require('./math.js');
console.log(math.add(2, 3));
```

**Pattern 2.**

```
// math.js
module.exports = {
    add: (x, y) => {
        return x + y;
    },
    multiply: (x, y) => {
        return x * y;
    }
};

// app.js
const math = require('./math.js');
console.log(math.add(2, 3));
```

Comment: Your two patterns are exactly the same for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `module.exports` is an empty object.  So, there is really no difference in result between your two patterns.

Your first pattern is just adding methods one at a time to the default empty object.

Your second pattern is creating a new object, adding methods to it and then replacing the default `module.exports` object with your new object.

> Which is the better pattern to use when creating modules in Node.js
>   that have multiple functions that are called "statically" i.e. not
>   using the new keyword.

The result is the same either way and it is merely a matter of a coding style preference for which way you like to write the code.

> Is there an equivalent in ES6 I am missing?

ES6 doesn't really introduce anything new for this.  You're just defining properties of an object.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no "correct way" or "correct pattern" for that. In both cases you are telling mostly the same thing. You're just writing it a little bit different. Both will be transformed in an object and imported by some other module.

That being said, I like the second one. It gives me a sense of better "bundling".

I would, though, import as

```
import { add, multiply } from './math'
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using `import` over `require`?

Comment: `import` was introduced in ES6 and allows you to use these: `{ field1, field2 }`, which is a little bit simpler than `const field1 = require('library.field1'); const field2 = require('library.field2')`

Comment: @BrunoMoutinho There are differences between `import` and `require`, but what you mention as being only available with `import` is not true since you can also use `const { field1, field2 } = require('library')`.